# Using flot for time series plotting

Tags: javascript, html, plot, flot

I am attempting to plot an array of the form [epoch, value]. There are several values taken at the same time (about 16 samples per second). For that, I chose to use Flot. I imported the data from JSON to arrays and passed it through in the same format as this example:

view-source:www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time/index.html

Although the box shows up fine, the x axis is unlabelled and there are no values whatsoever. Any help is appreciated.

My code:
https://jsfiddle.net/zanqzxj0/

I realize it's messy. Sorry about that.

The function I use for plotting:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [newHeart], {
            xaxis: { mode: "time",
      minTickSize: [1, "hour"],
                        min: (new Date(2018, 03, 1)).getTime(),
                        max: (new Date(2018, 03, 1)).getTime(),
                        twelveHourClock: true
 }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the wrong format for the timestamps, it should be epoch (UNIX time). I'll switch over to plotly.